# specific area scanning by Delphi twain

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, twain

How i can determine the x,y start and the x,y end of scanning using the [Delphi twain library](http://delphitwain.sourceforge.net/) ?

Also How i can set dpi for scan a document.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, for setting a region to be scanned, you can use `TTwainSource.SetImageLayoutFramework` method. `TDelphiTwain.Source` returns available Twain sources.

For DPI, I guess you should first set CapUnits to tuInches using `TTwainSource.SetICapUnits` method. Then you can set DPI by calling `TTwainSource.SetIXResolution` and `TTwainSource.SetIYResolution` methods.