# How can I scan a 300dpi image and save in TIFF format using Delphi?

Tags: delphi, gdi+, twain

I'm using Delphitwain (delphitwain.sourceforge.net) to add scan functionality to my app. Scanning is working fine and I can save bmp and jpeg files. Now I need to:

- save in 300dpi (the scanner is capable)
- save in TIFF format

After digging around, I found 2 tips:

http://www.delphipraxis.net/132787-farbstich-nach-bitmap-operation.html

http://synopse.info/fossil/wiki?name=GDI%2B

Here is my final code:

```
procedure TForm1.GoAcquireClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Counter := 0;
  Twain.SourceManagerLoaded := TRUE;
  Twain.LoadSourceManager;
  Twain.TransferMode := ttmMemory;

  with Twain.Source[ 0 ] do
  begin
    Loaded := TRUE;
    SetIXResolution(300);
    SetIYResolution(300);
    SetIBitDepth(1);
    EnableSource(true, true);
    while Enabled do Application.ProcessMessages;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.TwainTwainAcquire(Sender: TObject; const Index: Integer;
   Image: TBitmap; var Cancel: Boolean);
var
   TiffHolder: TSynPicture;
begin
  Inc( Counter );
  Current := Counter;
  ImageHolder.Picture.Assign( Image );
  ImageHolder.Picture.Bitmap.Monochrome := true;
  ImageHolder.Picture.Bitmap.Pixelformat := pf1Bit;

  SynGDIPlus.SaveAs(ImageHolder.Picture, format('c:\temp\teste%d.tif',[ Counter ]), gptTIF );
end;
```

Result: the image still is 96dpi and were saved as BMP (even with TIF extension).

What am I missing?

Comment: Great question. Please post your Delphi version.  I would suggest you change the subject to how to change the DPI from 96 to 300.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059343/twain-scanning-components-for-delphi   (not a duplicate because this new question boils down to how to change the DPI and file-format on the scan using these same Twain components, probably a property setup issue)

Comment: Thanks for your tip Warren. I would keep the word "scan" instead of "change resolution" because I don´t know if the acquired image is already in 300dpi or it was changed after I manipulated it on Image parameter.

Comment: Delphi 7. But I have licences for newer versions if a new version solves my problem :)

Comment: GraphicsEx by Mike Liksche (of VirtualTreeView fame) can read and yes, write, TIFF files. I would give it a try - http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=13&Itemid=33

Comment: TIFF generations is working now but scan is not saving in 300dpi. I read question [Question 4536227](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536227/specific-area-scanning-by-delphi-twain) but I could not imagine where do I have to put that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving TIFF files is hard in Delphi. I don't know any free/open source modules that do this.

[ImageEn](http://www.xequte.com/imageen/info/index.html) works.

In the past I have used saving as bmp and converting to tiff with irfanview through createprocess with the commandline 
'i_view32.exe c:\temp\scanned.bmp /bpp=1 /convert=c:\temp\scanned.tif'

Comment: If you read better the OP question, you'll see it uses an Open Source wrapper to the GDI+ library for saving tiff pictures.

Comment: He also said that the files came out internally as BMP files although they have the .tif extension

Comment: The fact that the wrapper has an issue does not mean that it would not be able to save TIFF. GDI+ is able to save TIFF pictures. It's the easiest way of doing it in Delphi.

Comment: Currently it isn't the easiest way because it doesn't work, whereas I provided 2 working solutions that admittedly have their own drawbacks.

Comment: I will keep trying using open/free software before trying some more drastic solution using jailed software.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, the irfanview solution is not an option on this project because I intend to distribute it to several users and the irfanview installation could be a additional problem to solve.

Comment: After trying several free/open components, the only one that saves on 300dpi is ImageEn 3. It's not cheap but it works very well, scanning and generating TIFF with all its attributes.

Answer (score 1):

The GDI+ library is able to save tiff pictures.

The SynGdiPlus unit use {557CF405-1A04-11D3-9A73-0000F81EF32E} for its TIFF encoder.

From the `TSynPicture.SaveAs` code, I see two possibilities:

- Either you don't have the corresponding TIFF encoder installed;
- Either there is some missing parameter expected by the TIFF encoder.

Try this version:

```
type
  /// the optional TIFF compression levels
  // - use e.g. ord(evCompressionCCITT4) to save a TIFF picture as CCITT4
  TGDIPPEncoderValue = (
    evColorTypeCMYK,
    evColorTypeYCCK,
    evCompressionLZW,
    evCompressionCCITT3,
    evCompressionCCITT4,
    evCompressionRle,
    evCompressionNone,
    (...)
    evFrameDimensionPage);

const
  EncoderCompression: TGUID = '{e09d739d-ccd4-44ee-8eba-3fbf8be4fc58}';

function TSynPicture.SaveAs(Stream: TStream; Format: TGDIPPictureType;
  CompressionQuality: integer): TGdipStatus;
var fStream: IStream;
    Len,Dummy: Int64;
    tmp: pointer;
    Params: TEncoderParameters;
    PParams: pointer;
    MS: TMemoryStream absolute Stream;
begin
  if not Gdip.Exists or (Stream=nil) or (fImage=0) then begin
    result := stInvalidParameter;
    exit;
  end;
  Params.Count := 1;
  Params.Parameter[0].Type_ := EncoderParameterValueTypeLong;
  Params.Parameter[0].NumberOfValues := 1;
  Params.Parameter[0].Value := @CompressionQuality;
  PParams := nil;
  case Format of
  gptJPG: if CompressionQuality>=0 then begin
    Params.Parameter[0].Guid := EncoderQuality;
    PParams := @Params;
  end;
  gptTIF: begin
    if not (TGDIPPEncoderValue(CompressionQuality) in [
        evCompressionLZW, evCompressionCCITT3, evCompressionCCITT4,
        evCompressionRle, evCompressionNone]) then
      // default tiff compression is LZW
      CompressionQuality := ord(evCompressionLZW);
    Params.Parameter[0].Guid := EncoderCompression;
    PParams := @Params;
  end;
  end;
  CreateStreamOnHGlobal(0, true, fStream);
  (...)
```

It will add the `EncoderCompression` parameter for TIFF pictures, which [seems to be required](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533839%28VS.85%29.aspx).

I've updated the source code repository version to include this correction.

Comment: Merci Beaucoup! Tiff generation works great. But it didn´t save in 300dpi. But I think this is not related to your library. The error should be in Twain config.